# Не понимаю поведения класса при добавлении к нему ul

Tags: html, css, css3, выравнивание, ul

В заголовке сформулировал вопрос.
 Пример  **кода** - [jsfiddle](https://liveweave.com/fTURNs)

```css
body {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.icons_main_class {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.icons_main_class li {
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/share/packs/174834-social-media-logos.png);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: 13rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.social1 {
  background-position: 20% -0.3%;
}

.social2 {
  background-position: 40% 0;
}

.social3 {
  background-position: 99% 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icons_main_class">
  <li class="social1"></li>
  <li class="social2"></li>
  <li class="social3"></li>
</ul>
```

Есть вот такой код, где я спрайтами попытался сделать что-то типа кнопок соц сетей и вроде бы все работает как надо. Но вот меня мучит один вопрос (реально хочу знать и понимать), если к классу `.icons_main_class` добавить `ul` (то есть так - `.icons_main_class ul {...}`) , то почему-то перестает работать `text-align`. Как я понимаю и меню эта слетает в исходное положение `(left)`. И вот мне интересно почему, ведь мы по сути обращаемся к классу, который содержится в том же теге ul, но если его прописать, то случается такая фигня, расскажите пожалуйста в чем дело и почему так происходит и еще когда добавляем этот `ul` то слева откуда то появляется `margin`, хотя в свойствах его нет, тоже непонятный момент.

Comment: Впишите код в теле вопроса так, он будет читаться и будущими поколениями кодеров у которых может возникнцуть схожая проблемма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
ul.icons_main_class {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
}


/* Потому, что ты не правильно последовательность селекторов прописываешь*/


/* ты говоришь, возьми тег ul который в каком то блоке классом icons_main_class2 */


/* и пропиши ему  правила ниже, а такой последовательности селекторов нет*/

.icons_main_class2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icons_main_class">
  <li class="social1">social1</li>
</ul>

<ul class="icons_main_class2">
  <li class="social1">social1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: понял, а margin откуда там если ul неправильно прописать? и еще - вижу что нужно прописывать без пробелов типа так ul.class... {} а если так, то не работает ul. class, но помню что второй вариант раньше часто использовал и кажись работало тоже или ошибаюсь? то есть всегда нужно писать без пробела в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Без пробела, что касается первого варианта работать будет, но это будет означать что ты хочешь задать правила  какому-то элементу с классом `.icons_main_class` который в `ul`

Comment: А `margin`, потому, что по умолчанию у всех элементов задан `margin` и `padding` по `8px`

Comment: но я же его обнуляю и для ul и для li

Comment: Ну ты же последовательность нарушил...  И правила не работали...